# IBM MobileFirst 7.0 - How to disable auto-update

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, auto-update

I made changes in the MobileFirst application and deployed on to the mobile device it is asking for "update for the application is available in android" How to disable it.

This is my authenticationConfig.xml file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <tns:loginConfiguration xmlns:tns="http://www.worklight.com/auth/config" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
     <staticResources>
     <!--  
            <resource id="logUploadServlet" securityTest="LogUploadServlet">
            <urlPatterns>/apps/services/loguploader*</urlPatterns>
        </resource>
        -->
        <resource id="subscribeServlet" securityTest="SubscribeServlet">
            <urlPatterns>/subscribeSMS*;/receiveSMS*;/ussd*</urlPatterns>
        </resource>
    </staticResources>      
     <securityTests>
        <!-- 
        <mobileSecurityTest name="mobileTests">
            <testAppAuthenticity/> 
            <testDeviceId provisioningType="none" />
            <testUser realm="myMobileLoginForm" />
            <testDirectUpdate mode="disabled" />
        </mobileSecurityTest>

        <webSecurityTest name="webTests">
            <testUser realm="myWebLoginForm"/>
        </webSecurityTest>
        <customSecurityTest name="customTests">
            <test realm="wl_antiXSRFRealm" step="1"/>
            <test realm="wl_authenticityRealm" step="1"/>
            <test realm="wl_remoteDisableRealm" step="1"/>
            <test realm="wl_directUpdateRealm" mode="perSession" step="1"/>
            <test realm="wl_anonymousUserRealm" isInternalUserID="true" step="1"/>
            <test realm="wl_deviceNoProvisioningRealm" isInternalDeviceID="true" step="2"/>
        </customSecurityTest>
        <customSecurityTest name="LogUploadServlet">
            <test realm="wl_anonymousUserRealm" step="1"/>
            <test realm="LogUploadServlet" isInternalUserID="true"/>
        </customSecurityTest>
        -->
        <customSecurityTest name="SubscribeServlet">
            <test realm="SubscribeServlet" isInternalUserID="true"/>
        </customSecurityTest>           
     </securityTests> 
        <realms>
        <realm name="SampleAppRealm" loginModule="StrongDummy">
        <className>com.worklight.core.auth.ext.FormBasedAuthenticator</className>
        </realm>

        <realm name="SubscribeServlet" loginModule="rejectAll">
            <className>com.worklight.core.auth.ext.HeaderAuthenticator</className>          
        </realm>
                <!-- For client logger -->
        <!-- <realm name="LogUploadServlet" loginModule="StrongDummy">
            <className>com.worklight.core.auth.ext.HeaderAuthenticator</className>
        </realm -->

        <!-- For websphere -->
        <!-- realm name="WASLTPARealm" loginModule="WASLTPAModule">
            <className>com.worklight.core.auth.ext.WebSphereFormBasedAuthenticator</className>
            <parameter name="login-page" value="/login.html"/>
            <parameter name="error-page" value="/loginError.html"/>
        </realm -->

        <!-- For User Certificate Authentication -->
        <!-- realm name="wl_userCertificateAuthRealm" loginModule="WLUserCertificateLoginModule">
            <className>com.worklight.core.auth.ext.UserCertificateAuthenticator</className>
            <parameter name="dependent-user-auth-realm" value="WASLTPARealm" />
            <parameter name="pki-bridge-class" value="com.worklight.core.auth.ext.UserCertificateEmbeddedPKI" />
            <parameter name="embedded-pki-bridge-ca-p12-file-path" value="/opt/ssl_ca/ca.p12"/> 
            <parameter name="embedded-pki-bridge-ca-p12-password" value="capassword" />
        </realm -->

        <!-- For Trusteer Fraud Detection -->
        <!-- Requires acquiring Trusteer SDK --> 
        <!-- realm name="wl_basicTrusteerFraudDetectionRealm" loginModule="trusteerFraudDetectionLogin">
            <className>com.worklight.core.auth.ext.TrusteerAuthenticator</className>
            <parameter name="rooted-device" value="block"/>
            <parameter name="device-with-malware" value="block"/>
            <parameter name="rooted-hiders" value="block"/>
            <parameter name="unsecured-wifi" value="alert"/>
            <parameter name="outdated-configuration" value="alert"/>
        </realm -->

    </realms>

    <loginModules>
        <loginModule name="StrongDummy">
            <className>com.worklight.core.auth.ext.NonValidatingLoginModule</className>
        </loginModule>

        <loginModule name="requireLogin">
            <className>com.worklight.core.auth.ext.SingleIdentityLoginModule</className>
        </loginModule>

        <loginModule name="rejectAll">
            <className>com.worklight.core.auth.ext.RejectingLoginModule</className>
        </loginModule>

        <!-- Required for Trusteer - wl_basicTrusteerFraudDetectionRealm -->        
        <!-- loginModule name="trusteerFraudDetectionLogin">
            <className>com.worklight.core.auth.ext.TrusteerLoginModule</className>
        </loginModule-->

        <!-- For websphere -->
        <!-- loginModule name="WASLTPAModule">
            <className>com.worklight.core.auth.ext.WebSphereLoginModule</className>
        </loginModule -->

        <!-- Login module for User Certificate Authentication -->
        <!-- <loginModule name="WLUserCertificateLoginModule">
            <className>com.worklight.core.auth.ext.UserCertificateLoginModule</className>
        </loginModule> -->


        <!-- For enabling SSO with no-provisioning device authentication -->
        <!-- <loginModule name="MySSO" ssoDeviceLoginModule="WLDeviceNoProvisioningLoginModule">
            <className>com.worklight.core.auth.ext.NonValidatingLoginModule</className>
        </loginModule> -->


        <!-- For enabling SSO with auto-provisioning device authentication -->
        <!-- <loginModule name="MySSO" ssoDeviceLoginModule="WLDeviceAutoProvisioningLoginModule">
            <className>com.worklight.core.auth.ext.NonValidatingLoginModule</className>
        </loginModule> -->
    </loginModules>

</tns:loginConfiguration>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you can "disable auto-update" easily. try this way

### Mobile security test

If a Direct Update test is not specified in a mobile security test, it is enabled with the default `perSession` mode. To change the direct update mode to `perRequest` in a mobile security test, add a direct update test with `mode="perRequest"` to a mobile security test: `<testDirectUpdate mode="perRequest"/>`. To disable direct update in a mobile security test, add a direct update test with `mode="disabled"` to the mobile security test: `<testDirectUpdate mode="disabled"/>`.

### Custom security test

To add a Direct Update test to a custom security test, add the following test to the security test: `<test realm="wl_directUpdateRealm"/>`. The default mode is `perSession`. To change the mode, specify a value for the mode attribute: `<test realm="wl_directUpdateRealm" mode="perRequest"/>`. To disable automatic Direct Update in a custom security test, either set the mode to disabled or do not add a test with a Direct Update realm.

Now ,re-build the project and re-deploy the .war file  (local server,production server) as well use an updated application

more information https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/admin/c_direct_update_as_security_realm.html?lang=en

Answer (score 1):

Remove the Direct Update security test from your security tests in authenticationConfig.xml. If in a non-development (Studio/CLI) environment, make sure to also re-build the project and re-deploy the .war file as well use an updated application.

Comment: I updated my authenticationConfig.xml file could you please tell me where do I need to change.